# Magento 2 - Incorrect title showing for some pages

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, contact-us, advanced-search, page-title

Some of the pages show incorrect title and heading : it is showing "Customer Login" as page heading and title for Contact page and Advanced Search page.

The point is, I included customer login form on every page including these above, but anywhere else I can edit the page title successfully...

How to edit these pages title and heading ?

Comment: Have you installed any third party extension for Customer login like login with facebook etc?

Comment: Nope, but I've a custom theme that shows a customer login form in header on every pages. The weirdest thing is that on every pages but these two, I can change the page title easily...

Comment: So you want to change only `Contact page and Advanced Search page` titles?

Comment: Not only, but yes, I want to change these pages title.
I tried to add this snippet :
`<referenceBlock name="page.main.title">
            <action method="setPageTitle">
                <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">BLAH BLAH</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>` in contact_index_index.xml but it didn't work.

Comment: What is the location of this file `contact_index_index.xml` this should be in `/app/design/frontend/Vendor/ThemeName/Magento_Contact/layout`.

Comment: It is. I solved it, I'll auto-answer my post soon !

Answer (score 5):

Solved it. The problem was that I had a layout using `Magento\Customer\Block\Form\Login`, like this:

```
<block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Form\Login" name="login.sidebar" template="form/login_sidebar.phtml">
    <container name="form.additional.info" as="form_additional_info"/>
</block>
```

I saw that `Magento\Customer\Block\Form\Login` class was overriding `_prepareLayout()` function like this:

```
/**
 * @return $this
 */
protected function _prepareLayout()
{
    $this->pageConfig->getTitle()->set(__('Customer Login'));
    return parent::_prepareLayout();
}
```

So I created a custom Block in `app/code/MyVendor/MyModule/Block/Form/Login` extending `Magento\Customer\Block\Form\Login`and overriding `_prepareLayout()` function like this:

```
<?php

namespace MyVendor\MyModule\Block\Form;

use Magento\Customer\Block\Form\Login as BaseLogin;

class Login extends BaseLogin
{
    /**
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        return $this;
    }
}
```

And then I replaced in my custom layout this:

```
<block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Form\Login" name="login.sidebar" template="form/login_sidebar.phtml">
    <container name="form.additional.info" as="form_additional_info"/>
</block>
```

by that:

```
<block class="MyVendor\MyModule\Block\Form\Login" name="login.sidebar" template="Magento_Customer::form/login_sidebar.phtml">
    <container name="form.additional.info" as="form_additional_info"/>
</block>
```

And the issue was solved!

Comment: I try it above code its working fine for affected pages but it also removes the title from customer login page.