# Various pages displaying "Customer Login" instead of their proper page title as defined in the xml page

Tags: magento2, layout, login, page-title

My Contact Us page, Password Reset, Forgotten password and possibly a few other pages are having their page title overriten to say "Customer Login". I have a feeling that the culprit is located here,...

`vendor\magento\module-customer\Block\Form\Login.php`

```
    protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        $this->pageConfig->getTitle()->set(__('Customer Login'));
        return parent::_prepareLayout();
    }
```

My layout files seem to be ignored and the title does not actually change. For example,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <title>Forgot Your Password</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="root">
            <action method="setHeaderTitle">
                <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Password forgotten</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\Forgotpassword" name="forgotPassword" template="Magento_Customer::form/forgotpassword.phtml">
                <container name="form.additional.info" as="form_additional_info"/>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

does not actually do anything

I was able to find some hints [on this stack post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/181276/magento-2-incorrect-title-showing-for-some-pages) but it did not seem to do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find my answer by looking at a couple different posts. I went ahead and followed [This Post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/181276/magento-2-incorrect-title-showing-for-some-pages) and created my class and saving it in MyVendor\MyModule\Block\Form as Login.php

```
<?php

namespace MyVendor\MyModule\Block\Form;

use Magento\Customer\Block\Form\Login as BaseLogin;

class Login extends BaseLogin
{
    /**
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        return $this;
    }
}
```

then edited my di.xml in `MyVendor\MyModule\etc` to include

```
<preference for="Magento\Customer\Block\Form\Login" type="MyVendor\MyModule\Block\Form\Login" />
```

More information on the cause of the issue can be found on [this stack post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/254865/route-shows-user-login-page-title?rq=1)